# Keyup event fires on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

jsfiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/m3g6rjok/1/

html

```
<textarea id="feedback" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" maxlength="50">Enter text here...</textarea>
<br>
<input type="text" value="10" id="lenbox"></input>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#feedback" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
      alert(value)
    $( "#lenbox" ).val( value );
  })
  .keyup();

})
```

I need to calculate the number of words thats entered on the textarea and need to display it on the text box below..I'm using the keyup event to check but it gets triggered even on the page load. How can I fix it

Comment: Do you want this to happen when a user presses enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.keyup();` from your code. This triggers the keyup event on page load.

Comment: He is also trying to calculate the words. Just removing keyup() does not solve his problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `keyup` event is raised because you trigger one. Remove the `.keyup()` after your handler function declaration:

```
$("#feedback").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value)
    $("#lenbox").val(value);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `.keyup();` at the end of your JQuery statement.
*Just remove it*

Answer (score 0):

You should not trigger the keyUp again. Also, you should move the code that's updating the value outside of the keyUp function, so you can also trigger the code on page load. After you've done that, it's just taking a string, split on spaces and count the words:

```
var calculateCount = function() {
  var value = $('#feedback').val();
  var count = value.split(" ").length;
  $( "#lenbox" ).val( count );
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#feedback").keyup(calculateCount);
  calculateCount();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qd6aznwa/

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/m3g6rjok/3/)

First, Remove `.keyup()` as has been pointed out already
Then, use `input` instead of `keyup` so that I can also catch **pasted** text.
Finally, count the number of words by using the `split` method and the `length` property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $( "#feedback" ).on('input',function() {            
        $( "#lenbox" ).val( this.value.split(' ').length );
    });    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you dont mind using HTML5 use the placeholder property

```
<textarea id="feedback" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" maxlength="50"  placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea>
```